# Add Markers inside Polygon on google maps every X meters² Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon, android-maps

I'm developing an application to Android and I need to add markers every 1000meters² inside a Polygon.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Polygon poly;
    private boolean isMarked;

    public void btClick(){
        if(isMarked){
            //Add markers inside polygon here
        }    
    }

   ...
}
```

I need it to be equally spaced. I mean, inside this polygon i need to insert a marker every 1000meters.. Like a grid..

[image]

Something like this...  each "." is a marker that i inserted

Comment: You need to get a lot more specific. Your question is much too vague for anyone to be able to guess what you mean. The X square maters could be in any shape and the markers placed could be in any position in the Polygon. Or are they to be equally spaced?

Comment: I need it to be equally spaced. I mean, inside this polygon i need to insert a marker every 1000meters.. Like a grid..  I will edit this....

Comment: Every 1000meters or every 1000 square meters? a polygon or a polyLine?
Area or distance? Ok, your image is a square. Is the poly always a square?

Comment: Always a polygon.. and the markers need to be at at least 1000 meters from any other marker, so 1 marker in the middle of each area of 1000 square meters. not aways a square. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something like that.. m50 is 50meters..

```
    double add = (m50*20)*distHa;
    for(double a=menLat; a<=maiLat; a+=add){
        for(double b=menLng; b<=maiLng; b+=add){
            try {
                Marker marked = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(a, b)
                                )
                );
                markers.add(marked);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("erro", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How will you ensure that it is inside a polygon? can you post full code

Comment: The variables "menLat","maiLat","menLng" and "maiLng" are the minimum and maximum latitide and longitude of the polygon. Usually you can get this variables calling some method like "getBounds()" or iterating over all points and searching for this information

Comment: can we able to add a marker on a polyline for a particular distance in android?